"Reference Request" or lack of motivation to self-research?
As many will know, every now and again, I go on the hunt through the Garbage Valley and look to see if there are any question gems out there which may need a little nudging.  If I can answer them I do.
Along with the usual issues with the old unanswered questions (which can demotivate you after a while of carrying out the task of some Garbage Valley clean-up) there is another pattern I may be seeing, maybe it is not there at all.  Hence, this question.
Let's look at Does a baby go for the most hard-to-get out of two presented objects? as an example.  In essence it could be seen as a reference-request question, therefore the tag could be added to it and it would be bumped to the top of the active queue for people to review and answer if they can.
I feel though that the tag is to be used with caution because, as @Josh pointed out in Do we need the "reference request" tag?.

the tag is being misused and we should remove it from questions unless they are looking for a specific article.

If you look at the meta-description for the tag, you see that the tag is for

questions where the author is looking for a specific article/survey/book on a given statement/conclusion.

Does a baby go for the most hard-to-get out of two presented objects? is not looking for a specific article/survey/book per se. To me, they have a hypothesis which they have outlined, and they are giving it to us to look for scientific research on their behalf.  Research which may not even exist in the first place.
As @AliceD suggested

The weighting factor could, and probably should be, the chance it will be answered. If that chance is low, and the odds are against it due to quality reasons - close it.

So, I have voted this question for closure for now. If there is strong reason to consider it to be a reference-request question, I may retract it.
What would be the consensus on the idea of tagging all questions of this type as reference-request?  Should they really be closed under the "not framed in psychology or neuroscience" close vote reason due to lack of required prior research?

Hi Chris. Good to see you back. Just as a side note; the quote from me you provide is from the good ol' days when I was still talking Garbage Valley and targeting everything I could lay my hands on, dead or alive. Times have changed, also in part since we are graduated. Therefore, I would, personally, currently be a bit more hesitant with putting too much weight on answerability. Rather, question quality should be the defining factor. In the end, unanswerable questions can still be good. Bad questions shouldn't be closed because they are unanswerable, but because they are, well... bad :-)

Having said all that, great question and I find it more than admirable when people again take up their backpacks and tread Garbage Valley to continue the [seemingly] endless task of cleaning it up. Kudos.

"Bad questions shouldn't be closed because they are unanswerable, but because they are, well... bad :-)" Good point @AliceD

Thanks @ChrisRogers! I've removed this tag often from questions; it's easy as a non-expert to recognize when it's misapplied. As such, I vote abolish it. The other parts of your question here are still valuable.

"is not looking for a specific article/survey/book per se" I draw a different conclusion from reading that question. They seemingly know of some experiment, but they may not know whether it is published or not; maybe it is a popular science TV experiment. But, I think labeling it as a mere "hypothesis" is misrepresenting the OP.

Hmm, yes. @StevenJeuris Re-reading it I may have got the question wrong there. "I think I've read that babys statistically prefer the boxed fruit and tries to reach it first, "

probably I have missed this, but what is your expectation for this tag?

@Ooker - In the comments to StevenJeuris' answer he linked I responded by saying "I think I have to agree with you based on what you have said here. Not thought of it in that way". So I am inclined to abolish it too
